# flash builder NOT showing all icons while packging,

Tags: air, flash-builder

few component buttons update their icons dynamically, from "/src/icons" and it works well in debug. in release build, i noticed few icons are missing.
in packaging (release build) its not showing all of those icons(missing). any specific reason? or ideas?
i tried > clean project. it removes garbage from bin and recopy all data ( still miss those icons). which means, somehow it is not able to understand or relate with those icons.

Q. can we force packging dialog to load our icons ?
Q. am i missing something serious?
thanks in advance for time and replying..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you do not embed (using [Embed]tag) any of those icons in any of your classes. I believe if you embed an image that is in your source code Flash Builder will automaticaly assume you will no longer need it at runtime since the asset is now embedded into your swf, which seems appropriate from a certain perspective.

The rule I usually try follow is: if I am embedding something I put it in a lib folder outside of the src folder. If the asset needs to embedded AND loaded at runtime than have 2 copies; one in lib and the other in src.